# How to run Python script without asking password?

Tags: python

I'm trying to power on my system whenever I require. So I'm using the below commands, which run successfully. But when I run the code, it asks for my password and I have to supply the password manually every time.

```
os.system('sudo sh -c "echo 0 > /sys/class/rtc/rtc0/wakealarm"' % locals())     
os.system('sudo sh -c "echo %(turnontime)s > /sys/class/rtc/rtc0/wakealarm"' % locals())
```

How can I run this code without it asking for my password?

Comment: The `sudo` command will give you root privileges, and needs your password to do so. It's a really, really bad idea to give root access without a password.

Comment: Also, why are you using Python? It's just making system calls. You'd be much better off just using a shell script.

Comment: Dude, i can understood that the sudo command will give root privileges, but i know through supprocess.call() will get the password from one variable(need to define password to variable) and the system read automatically.But i don't know how will declare that.

Comment: This has been asked enough times on SO that it's hard to find the right answer (probably because it's not a programming question, and should be on unix.stackexchange.com). Look into the sudoers file for commands that will run with sudo without needing a password.

Answer (score 4):

Having your root password in a script file is just plain stupid. *Don't do it*, there are better alternatives. [This](http://www.tuxation.com/setuid-on-shell-scripts.html) page describes how to make a shell script with the [setuid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setuid) bit set, and how to circumvent the restriction most modern Linux distributions have on setuid on shell scripts.

I'll summarize the salient parts here to comply with stackoverflow guidelines. First make a `.c` file (let's say it's called `runscript.c`) with this contents:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main()
{
   setuid( 0 );
   system( "/path/to/script.sh" ); 

   return 0;
}
```

Install gcc (`apt-get install gcc` on debian based distro's), then type

```
gcc -o runscript runscript.c
```

Now, as root, type

```
chown root:root runscript script.sh
chmod 4755 runscript script.sh
```

Now any user should be able to run `runscript`, and it will execute `script.sh` as if the user was root.

As long as both files are owned by root and not writeable by anyone else than root, this is *fairly* secure, and much more secure than embedding the root password in plaintext in a script file.

I've not succeeded in making this work for a `script.py` file for some reason, so if you *really* want to run a python script, have the `script.sh` file run it indirectly. If you do this, remember to set owner and permissions for the python script as well, using `chown` and `chmod` as above.

Answer (score 3):

`sudo` when run with a `-S` option will read the password from the stdin.

In that case you could use it in a script like:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo my_awesome_password | sudo -S python awesome_script.py
```

As @david correctly says, why are you using python to just execute system calls? You could probably have this same script doing the same.